# Prove that these two products of cyclic groups are isomorphic to each other.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{18}\times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_{36}\times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ are isomorphic groups.

Here order of the 2 groups are same. Also I know that  $Z_m \times Z_n$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $Z_{mn}$ iff $(m,n)=1$. But I don't know to find the group which is isomorphic to $Z_m \times Z_n$  where m and n are not relatively prime.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Z}_{4}\times\mathbf{Z}_{18}\times\mathbf{Z}_{15}
  &\cong \mathbf{Z}_{4}\times\mathbf{Z}_{2}\times\mathbf{Z}_{9}\times\mathbf{Z}_{3}\times\mathbf{Z}_{5} \\
  &\cong \mathbf{Z}_{3}\times\mathbf{Z}_{9}\times\mathbf{Z}_{4}\times \dots
\end{align*}
$$